# Python functional programming self-exercise

Tags: python, functional-programming

I realise that using a functional paradigm everywhere does not always result in very readable code -- the code segment below is something I'm doing just as an exercise. What I'm trying to do is as follows :-

> Given a list of strings(L) and a string(S) I need to find L[i]^S. If S exists in L, don't xor the strings together. L[i]^S would mean xoring the bytes in the same position with each other.

This is how I proceeded to solve the problem. I tried to break it down to its simplest form - i.e. xoring of two characters. If one of the inputs wouldn't be a character, I return a "".(I couldn't think of a better way to do this).

```
xor_char   = lambda x, y: (chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) if x and y else "")
assert xor_char(None, "a") == ""
assert xor_char("a", " ")  == "A"
```

Next, I try to write some code to xor the strings together.

```
from operator import add
xor_string = lambda string_one, string_two: reduce(add, (map(xor_char, string_one, string_two) if string_one != string_two else ""))
assert xor_string("asdf", "asdfg") == "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
assert xor_string("asdf", "    ")  == "ASDF"
```

Then, finally I try to perform this on a list of strings and a string.

```
xor_list_string = lambda l, s: map(xor_string, l, [s]*len(l))
print xor_list_string(a_list, a_string)
```

I get an error as follows on running the above line :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "2.py", line 23, in main
    analyze(all_lines, all_lines[-1])
  File "2.py", line 18, in analyze
    print xor_list_string(a_list, a_string)
  File "2.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    xor_list_string = lambda l, s: map(xor_string, l, [s]*len(l))
  File "2.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    xor_string = lambda string_one, string_two: reduce(add, (map(xor_char, string_one, string_two) if string_one != string_two else ""))
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there anything wrong with how I'm trying to solve the problem using functional programming?
- Any obvious improvements you can think of?(the improvements would have to adhere to the functional paradigm too -- I'm doing this as a thought exercise, not in any project).

Comment: Pass an initializer (3rd parameter) to `reduce` to specify the behavior when the iterable is empty. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: @uki What are the values of `a_list` and `a_string`?

Comment: @thefourtheye dummy values of a_list could be ["asdf", "asdfg", "qwer"] and a_string could be "qwer".

Answer (score 4):

I'd xor 2 strings together using `zip`:

```
l = [ord(s1) ^ ord(s2) for s1,s2 in zip(str1,str2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to pass the initializer to `reduce` like this

```
reduce(add, (map(xor_char, string_one, string_two) if string_one != string_two else ""), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, is far as i understand you need to each string `l` in list of strings `L` to be xored with string `b` if there are not equal. You can use list comprehension for that:

```
In [1]: L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
In [2]: S = 'c'
In [3]: [ chr( ord(l) ^ ord(S)) if l is not S else S for l in L]
Out[3]: ['\x02', '\x01', 'c', '\x07', '\x06', '\x05']
```

We are using `for l in L` to iterate through L list, then we are checking if l element is equal to S ( `if l is not S else S` ) and if that works we doing xor-ing part.

Ok i've played around with your code. Problem with generator inside reduce. It gives you empty list in case strings are identical. You can fix that by moving `if` in to lambda instead of reduce. Like this:

```
a_list = [ 'as', 'qwe', 'vcs', 'ase', 'wsc', 'ase', 'sa' ]
a_string = 'sa'

xor_char   = lambda x, y: (chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) if x and y else "")
assert xor_char(None, "a") == ""
assert xor_char("a", " ")  == "A"

from operator import add
xor_string = lambda string_one, string_two: reduce(add, map(xor_char, string_one, string_two)) if string_one != string_two else ''
assert xor_string("asdf", "asdfg") == "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
assert xor_string("asdf", "    ")  == "ASDF"

xor_list_string = lambda l, s: map(xor_string, l, [s]*len(l))
print xor_list_string(a_list, a_string)
```

Output:

```
['\x12\x12', '\x02\x16', '\x05\x02', '\x12\x12', '\x04\x12', '\x12\x12', '']
```